# kafka ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector,

Tags: sql-server, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Running kafka on windows. Getting the error below while trying to start kafka connect using the command:

> .\bin\windows\connect-standalone.bat .\config\worker.properties .\config\connector.properties

Using the plugin `plugin.path=C:\Kafka\kafka_2.12-2.7.0\plugins\debezium-connector-sqlserver\` on `connect-standalone.properties` file.

Any idea why the plugin is not recognized by kafka conenct?

Error:

```
[2021-02-18 08:21:16,384] ERROR Failed to create job for .\config\connector.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
[2021-02-18 08:21:16,384] ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='2.7.0', encodedVersion=2.7.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.c
```

Comment: Try set `plugin.path` as follows: plugin.path=C:\Kafka\kafka_2.12-2.7.0\plugins\

Comment: Probably shouldn't run direct on windows anyway https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 1):

you should set the plugin path as
plugin.path=C:\Kafka\kafka_2.12-2.7.0\plugins

dont set to the deepest file path

Answer (score 0):

In windows, It works after modifying the plugin path in connect-standalone.properties as \\{computername}\c$\kakfa.